# An inconsistency was detected

Tags: sql-server-2005, corruption, dbcc

Am running asp.net application.Am searching records.if i click the view button i got this error,

> an inconsistency was detected during an internal operation in
>   database(database name) on page(some page).please contact technical
>   support.reference number 6.

I Googled and i got the result as to run DBCC CHECKDB.
I run the following command in sql server 2005,

```
DBCC CHECKDB (database name) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

my result was something like this

> Table error: Object ID 1424372489, index ID 1, partition ID 374822652149760, alloc unit ID 93347675439104 (type In-row data). Page (1:72872) is missing a reference from previous page (1:72871). Possible chain linkage problem.
>   Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Object ID 1424372489, index ID 1, partition ID 374822652149760, alloc unit ID 93347675439104 (type In-row data): Page (1:109577) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
>   Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Table error: Object ID 1424372489, index ID 1, partition ID 374822652149760, alloc unit ID 93347675439104 (type In-row data). Page (1:109578) is missing a reference from previous page (1:109577). Possible chain linkage problem.
>   Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 10 consistency errors in table 'some table' (object ID 1424372489).
>
> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 5 consistency errors in table 'some table' (object ID 1432300808).
>
> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 19 consistency errors in database 'database name'.
>   repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (database name).

Comment: Are you accessing a database and what kind of database is it?

Comment: so is still there is an problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This inconsistency error can be resolved by running the following command:

```
dbcc checkdb(database name,repair_allow_data_loss)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Jeni said, you can run that command and it will do a repair, but CAN make it loose some data.

I would first start with:

> DBCC CHECKDB('DB Name',REPAIR_REBUILD)

If that fails use the command provided by jeni:

> dbcc checkdb(database name.repair_allow_data_loss)

But if you have to run with allow repair, consider restoring from backup.

Comment: Yes U r right . I got failed with that command and then tried the repair with data loss command.