# An inconsistency in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, corruption, exception

(could be) possible duplicate with [An inconsistency was detected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11235/an-inconsistency-was-detected)

I have small table that returns from query

> *UDA-SQL-0114 The cursor supplied to the operation "sqlOpenResult" is
>   inactive.UDA-SQL-0564 [Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0]An
>   inconsistency was detected during an internal operation. Please
>   contact technical support. (SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLERRORCODE=5243)*

- before any further steps on my side I want to ask if is there another way as is described in linked thread,
- and in this case there isn't any issue to re_creating table with proper contents on fly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message looks like it is coming from a DB2 linked server. I would check to make sure the consistency error is not being passed back from DB2.

Comment: .............thanks +1, there were AS400 replacement, then catalog id changed